Why do I get an error associated with native assets in flutter?
I am getting the following error when I run the flutter app or flutter pub get:
Macmohan-MacBook-Air facilify % flutter pub get 
Building flutter tool...
Resolving dependencies... (6.7s)
Downloading packages... 
Got dependencies.
../../packages/flutter_tools/lib/src/isolated/native_assets/native_assets.dart:48:10: Error: Type 'DryRunResult' not found.
  Future<DryRunResult> dryRun({
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../packages/flutter_tools/lib/src/isolated/native_assets/native_assets.dart:127:10: Error: Type 'DryRunResult' not found.
  Future<DryRunResult> dryRun({
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../packages/flutter_tools/lib/src/isolated/native_assets/native_assets.dart:754:37: Error: Type 'DryRunResult' not found.
void ensureNativeAssetsBuildSucceed(DryRunResult result) {
                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../packages/flutter_tools/lib/src/isolated/native_assets/native_assets.dart:123:26: Error: The getter 'packagesWithNativeAssets' isn't defined for the class 'PackageLayout'.
 - 'PackageLayout' is from 'package:native_assets_builder/src/package_layout/package_layout.dart' ('../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/native_assets_builder-0.7.0/lib/src/package_layout/package_layout.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'packagesWithNativeAssets'.
    return packageLayout.packagesWithNativeAssets;
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../packages/flutter_tools/lib/src/isolated/native_assets/native_assets.dart:137:25: Error: The method 'dryRun' isn't defined for the class 'NativeAssetsBuildRunner'.
 - 'NativeAssetsBuildRunner' is from 'package:native_assets_builder/src/build_runner/build_runner.dart' ('../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/native_assets_builder-0.7.0/lib/src/build_runner/build_runner.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'dryRun'.
    return _buildRunner.dryRun(
                        ^^^^^^
../../packages/flutter_tools/lib/src/isolated/native_assets/native_assets.dart:563:9: Error: 'DryRunResult' isn't a type.
  final DryRunResult dryRunResult = await buildRunner.dryRun(
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../packages/flutter_tools/lib/src/isolated/native_assets/native_assets.dart:754:37: Error: 'DryRunResult' isn't a type.
void ensureNativeAssetsBuildSucceed(DryRunResult result) {
                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../packages/flutter_tools/lib/src/isolated/native_assets/android/native_assets.dart:53:9: Error: 'DryRunResult' isn't a type.
  final DryRunResult dryRunResult = await buildRunner.dryRun(
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../packages/flutter_tools/lib/src/isolated/native_assets/ios/native_assets.dart:51:9: Error: 'DryRunResult' isn't a type.
  final DryRunResult dryRunResult = await buildRunner.dryRun(
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../packages/flutter_tools/lib/src/isolated/native_assets/macos/native_assets.dart:55:9: Error: 'DryRunResult' isn't a type.
  final DryRunResult dryRunResult = await buildRunner.dryRun(\

When I check the settings this is what I have:


Why would this happen? Any fix?

I used flutter 3.22.1. Tried to switch between older versions, but the only thing that helped me was to reinstall flutter. I use fvm destroy and fvm install
